# How to display another field instead of default field in a many2one field in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-13

I want to display a custom field in many2one field in odoo but only in a particular view, the sales order view.
These are my models

```py
 class SalesPartnerBankInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner.bank'

    display_on_sales = fields.Boolean(string='Display On Sales Quotation '
                                             'Report', readonly=False)
    location = fields.Char()
```

I want to display the location field in my many2one field in sales order.

```py
  class CustomSalesInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    quotation = fields.Text(string='Quotation Title', readonly=False,
                            compute='_compute_quotation_title',
    
    location = fields.Many2one('res.partner.bank', domain=[('location', '!=', None)],
                                string='Bank Account Location')
```

Comment: You can do that with computed or related fields. But first i miss a requirement here: where or when will the "res.partner.bank" record will be set? Or where do you get the data from? Your solution now will allow the user to set a bank account on sales orders which are pre-filtered (only show bank accounts with location field set). What is the bank account in your process context, the customer's or your company's bank account?

Comment: I do not understand you

Answer (score 1):

I don't really see where the real connection between bank accounts and sales orders are in your case, but a second field should work. But first you should rename the Many2one field to `res.partner.bank`.

```py
class CustomSalesInherit(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    # i've added display_on_sales to the domain
    # because the field names makes sense for using it here
    partner_bank_id = fields.Many2one(
        comodel_name='res.partner.bank',
        domain=[('location', '!=', None), ('display_on_sales', '=', True)],
        string='Bank Account Location')

    # related field to location
    location = fields.Char(related="partner_bank_id.location")
```